# Cluster Analysis for crowds of people

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, location, cluster-analysis, data-science

I have location data from a large number of users (hundreds of thousands). I store the current position and a few historical data points (minute data going back one hour).

How would I go about detecting crowds that gather around natural events like birthday parties etc.? Even smaller crowds (let's say starting from 5 people) should be detected.
The algorithm needs to work in almost real time (or at least once a minute) to detect crowds as they happen.

I have looked into many cluster analysis algorithms, but most of them seem like a bad choice. They either take too long (I have seen O(n^3) and O(2^n)) or need to know how many clusters there are beforehand.

Can someone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let each user be it's own cluster. When she gets within distance R to another user form a new cluster and separate again when the person leaves. You have your event when:

- Number of people is greater than N
- They are in the same place for the timer greater than T
- The party is not moving (might indicate a public transport)
- It's not located in public service buildings (hospital, school etc.)
- (good number of other conditions)

One minute is plenty of time to get it done even on hundreds of thousands of people. In naive implementation it would be O(n^2), but mind there is no point in comparing location of each individual, only those in close neighbourhood. In first approximation you can divide the "world" into sectors, which also makes it easy to make the task parallel - and in turn easily scale. More users? Just add a few more nodes and downscale.

One idea would be to think in terms of 'mass' and centre of gravity. First of all, do not mark something as event until the mass is not greater than e.g. 15 units. Sure, location is imprecise, but in case of events it should average around centre of the event. If your cluster grows in any direction without adding substantial mass, then most likely it isn't right. Look at methods like DBSCAN (density-based clustering), good inspiration can be also taken from physical systems, even Ising model (here you think in terms of temperature and "flipping" someone to join the crowd)ale at time of limited activity.

How to avoid "single-linkage problem" mentioned by author in comments? One idea would be to think in terms of 'mass' and centre of gravity. First of all, do not mark something as event until the mass is not greater than e.g. 15 units. Sure, location is imprecise, but in case of events it should average around centre of the event. If your cluster grows in any direction without adding substantial mass, then most likely it isn't right. Look at methods like DBSCAN (density-based clustering), good inspiration can be also taken from physical systems, even Ising model (here you think in terms of temperature and "flipping" someone to join the crowd). It is not a novel problem and I am sure there are papers that cover it (partially), e.g. [Is There a Crowd? Experiences in Using Density-Based Clustering and Outlier Detection](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-13817-6_16).

Comment: Thank you! The problem here is, that two nearby clusters might connect if a single user moves in between them. This can happen in densely populated areas very easily. (Single linkage problem)

Comment: How is this a problem? You get a single cluster then. You have to watch though to not chain-connect everyone in this manner (when people live close to each other). Since you have the coordinates, you should be able to detect such cases. The GPS obviously gives approximate location.

Comment: How would I do that? Maybe give an user who already linked to the event from relatively far away less "linking range"? And the time aspect: I might run the algorithm every minute and only if it detected an event at least 7 times in 10 minutes in this location, actually fire one? This way I have the time and space aspect figured out. I would also need to check if it were always roughly the same people

Comment: I expanded the answer to cover the linkage problem, I hope now it provides enough material to get you coding :).

Comment: Great! I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

There is little use in doing a full clustering.

Just uses good database index.

Keep a database of the current positions.

Whenever you get a new coordinate, query the database with the desired radius, say 50 meters. A *good* index will do this in O(log n) for a small radius. If you get enough results, this may be an event, or someone joining an ongoing event.